# "Setting up tick label, The disappearance of first array list, jumping up to the second array list", so basically why the first array not setted up?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Please see the result below, as you can see in the image when i set the label it suddenly jump to second list (x_tick[1] and y_tick[1])  why? what happen to first list (x_tick[0] and y_tick[0]).

When i use image to plot this happen but without image it show up.

Note: for image in matplotlib. y label, set from top to bottom and x label, set from left to right

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw



point=(1.28358, 103.86921, 1.11504, 104.16138) #BATAM3
im = Image.open('BATAM3.png', 'r')
x_tick = list(map(lambda x: round(x, 7), np.linspace(point[1], point[3], endpoint=True, num=9)))
y_tick = list(map(lambda x: round(x, 7), np.linspace(point[2], point[0], endpoint=True, num=6)))
y_tick = sorted(y_tick, reverse=True)


print(x_tick)
print(y_tick)
#print(x_tick[0])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
ax.imshow(im)
ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')
ax.set_xticklabels(x_tick)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_tick)
ax.grid()
```

This yields:

```
[103.86921, 103.9057312, 103.9422525, 103.9787737, 104.015295, 104.0518162, 104.0883375, 104.1248587, 104.16138]
[1.28358, 1.249872, 1.216164, 1.182456, 1.148748, 1.11504]
```

here the result for the image imshow(im) :

https://files.fm/thumb_show.php?i=c6u8b5bhg

to make my question easy to understand :

https://files.fm/thumb_show.php?i=7vucbyuhg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says, you need to set the ticks locations using set_xticks first before setting the labels.

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html

```
w, l = im.size
x_pos = list(map(lambda x: round(x), np.linspace(0, w, endpoint=True, num=9)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
ax.imshow(im)
ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')
ax.set_xticks(x_pos) #set the positions
ax.set_xticklabels(x_tick)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_tick)
ax.grid()
```

Comment: Thank a lot @Said Al Faraby, i never have this kind problem before if i just ploting graph. welp i guess i need to reread matplotlib documentation again but more carefully this time.

Answer (score 0):

it Solved, thanks to @Said Al Faraby for the answer.
Here the fix :

```
point=(1.28358, 103.86921, 1.11504, 104.16138)
im = Image.open('BATAM3.png', 'r')
x_pos = list(map(lambda x: round(x), np.linspace(0, im.size[0], endpoint=True, num=10)))
y_pos = list(map(lambda x: round(x), np.linspace(0, im.size[1], endpoint=True, num=6)))
x_tick = list(map(lambda x: round(x, 7), np.linspace(point[1], point[3], endpoint=True, num=10)))
y_tick = list(map(lambda x: round(x, 7), np.linspace(point[2], point[0], endpoint=True, num=6)))
y_tick = sorted(y_tick, reverse=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
ax.imshow(im)
ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')
ax.set_xticks(x_pos)
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_xticklabels(x_tick)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_tick)
ax.grid()
```

and here for the image :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kWl8.jpg